# Why customized stats() only show for the second regression in the Stata esttab table?

Tags: stata

Here are the codes. I would like Year fixed effects to appear in both columns. However, it shows in the second column only. How to make this happen? Thanks.

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg foreign
estadd local year_fe Yes

esttab, cells(b(fmt(a3)) t(fmt(2) par)) stats(year_fe r2 N, fmt(%-#s 3 0) 
labels("Year FE"))

--------------------------------------
                     est1         est2
                      b/t          b/t
--------------------------------------
weight              1.747        3.465
                   (2.72)       (5.49)
mpg                -49.51        21.85
                   (-0.57)       (0.29)
foreign                         3673.1
                                (5.37)
_cons              1946.1      -5853.7
                   (0.54)      (-1.73)
--------------------------------------
Year FE                            Yes
r2                  0.293        0.500
N                      74           74
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I have to "estadd local year_fe Yes" after each regression.